# How to solve the error 403 when doing requests?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to get data as json from a page. But my issue is that you need to be authenticated to the site to be able to see the page. I have an account on the site and I would like to know how to make the authentication or bypass this to be able to make my request, for the moment I have

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403
```

And here is the code I've made

```
import urllib.request, json

url =  "https://intra.epitech.eu/planning/"
json_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(json_url.read())
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The epitech intranet gives access to data only if you are logged in with your epitech account (i'm currently a epitech student building an app linked to the intra).

if you are not logged in to the intra you will get a 403 error (the one you have).

to connect to the intra with your account, you either need to use a autologin link (you can generate one in your intra settings) or register a [azure active directory](https://portal.azure.com) app to be able to log in with office365.

Comment: Yes I found the autologin link right after the question. But I have an issue though, when I try to get the planning of the intra, it doesn't generate the actual planning, even if I put the json for the date in it, it loads all data from the page except the planning, any idea ?

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck i'm not sure what you are trying to do, are you trying to get the json data of the planning?

Comment: Yes, I need it for a personnal project

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck i can link you to this gist made by another epitech student who started to document the intra: https://gist.github.com/demaisj/45a210a4ae13dc0b45dfbbdcf7d9a852. to get the json format, add at the end of the url  `?format=json`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use API of this website to get protected data. The fact you have an account does not allows you to get data programmatically.